# Python threading sync

Tags: python, multithreading, class

I have a base class that has an empty method called `Update`.
This `Update` method is inherited by X amount of different subclasses
The base class calls the `Update` method once every 30 ticks (right now it's not. It's just doing it in a loop right now, but I plan to make it get called every 30 ticks soon.)
Each subclass has its own method `Update` with its own set of instructions.
It's working fine. However there is one problem and that is all the threads are clashing together. When they print out a message in the python shell they are blended together.

I have done some research in to it but from what I have found it is confusing the heck out of me. All i want to do is have the output of obj1, obj2 and obj3 own there own lines and not smashed together.

here is my current code

```
import _thread
class BaseClass(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        _thread.start_new_thread( self.UpdateHandler,() )

    def ClassType(self):
        """Returns a string of the childs type"""
        pass

    def UpdateHandler(self):
        #this part handles when to call the update.
        #it is allso needed so that it can be run in a thread.
        while True:
            self.Update()

    def Update(self):
        #This is a place holder.
        #It stops classes that dont have a Update function crashing when called
        pass

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class ChildClassA(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super(ChildClassA, self).__init__(name)

    def ClassType(self):
        return 'ChildClassA'

    def Update(self):
        print(self.name, ": is doing stuff CLASS A")

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class ChildClassB(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super(ChildClassB, self).__init__(name)

    def Update(self):
        print(self.name, "This is a completley diffeent action CLASS B")
        self.Hi()

    def ClassType(self):
        return 'ChildClassB'

    def Hi(self):
        print("Hi")
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class ChildClassC(BaseClass): 
    def __init__(self, name): 
        super(ChildClassC, self).__init__(name) 

    def Update(self): 
        print(self.name, "This is a completley diffeent action")

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

obj1 = ChildClassA('Obj1') 
obj2 = ChildClassA('Obj2')
obj3 = ChildClassB('Obj3')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a `semaphore`, which is a multi-threaded lock object. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming).

You sometimes see the same principle in kindergarten or pre-schools where to go to the toilet you need to take a necklace or another object to indicate the toilet is not occupied.

A semaphore object has two operations traditionally called `P` and `V`. The `P` operation requests the lock. If the lock is currently taken, the thread will wait until the lock becomes free. The `V` operation will free the lock, allowing another thread a chance to take the lock. `P` and `V` are abbreviations for the Dutch words "plaatsen" en "vrijgeven" ("put" and "release").

In python you can create a semaphore object by using the `threading.Semaphore()` or the `_thread.request_lock()` factory functions. The resulting objects have two methods: `acquire` (=`P`) and `release` (=`V`).

```
import _thread
class BaseClass(object):
    lock = _thread.request_lock()
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        _thread.start_new_thread( self.UpdateHandler,() )

    def ClassType(self):
        """Returns a string of the childs type"""
        pass

    def UpdateHandler(self):
        #this part handles when to call the update.
        #it is allso needed so that it can be run in a thread.
        while True:
            self.lock.acquire()
            self.Update()
            self.lock.release()


    def Update(self):
        #This is a place holder.
        #It stops classes that dont have a Update function crashing   when called
        pass
```

Comment: Ok now that makes a lot of seance and sounds like it is exsatley what I am lookign for so im assuming it would be **something** like

`while True:
            threading.Semaphore.acquire()
            self.Update()
            threading.Semaphore.release()`

however this is part of the threading module. as apposed to the _thread module. and from the sites I have researched the threading module is what got me confused in the first place. Which is why I am using the old _thread module.

Comment: If you want to stay with just `_thread`, you can use `_thread.allocate_lock()`. The resulting lock object also has the methods `acquire` and `release`.